# AutoCompleteTextView - dropdown rows turn black on scroll in Android 2.3

Tags: android

I have a basic `AutoCompleteTextView` and an `ArrayAdapter` bound to it.  Works great on Android 4.*, but on 2.3 whenever I scroll the dropdown the rows render in all black.  If I tap on a row then the entire dropdown renders correctly.

In the below text, when the TextView is generated using `inflate`, if I set the background color to white (the commented out line) then it always shows white even when scrolling, but the tap selection effect (changing the row to the system tap a row color) doesn't work then.

I am using actionbarsherlock here but I would hope that wouldn't the the cause here.  Any ideas?

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GfJ32.png

```
public class AutocompleteAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> implements Filterable {

public AutocompleteAdapter(Context context) {
    super(context, android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);

    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    mContext = context;
}

@Override
public View getView(final int position, final View convertView, final ViewGroup parent) {
    final TextView tv;
    if (convertView != null) {
        tv = (TextView) convertView;
    } else {
        tv = (TextView) mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);
        //tv.setBackgroundColor(tv.getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    }

    tv.setText(getItem(position));
    return tv;
}
....
```

Comment: Ok, Because its scrolling cache.

Comment: If I disable using convertViews, still the same issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its because your theme is dark..

If your theme in Manifest.xml is light.. ie,

```
    <application
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Workaround" >
```

I've get it to work by adding 2 xml files in values folder..

**styles.xml**

```
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="android:Theme.Light" />
      <style name="AutoCompleteTextViewLight" parent="@android:style/Widget.AutoCompleteTextView">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    </style>
    <style name="Widget.DropDownItemLight" parent="@android:style/Widget.DropDownItem">
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_light</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

**theme.xml**

```
<resources>
    <style name="Theme.Light.NoTitleBar.Workaround" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light.NoTitleBar">
        <item name="android:autoCompleteTextViewStyle">@style/AutoCompleteTextViewLight</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownItemStyle">@style/Widget.DropDownItemLight</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

I couldnt find another way...

Comment: Looks like the theme is the issue.  Your specific fix didn't work but its a great pointer for now.

Comment: @user910046 : it works only for light theme.. u just try changing the light values in this to dark.. change `@android:color/primary_text_light` to `@android:color/primary_text_dark`.. may be it'll work

Comment: I used an automated theme generator for Actionbarsherlock which had an entry for android:listSelector.  Removing that seems to have fixed it.

Answer (score 1):

I believe, the DropDown background and TextColor depends on the Theme of your application or the default theme of the device.

Since, you said it worked fine on few devices(i had the same issue). Its always good to use a custom DropDownItem.

Instead of:

```
tv = (TextView) mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line, parent, false);
```

using `simple_dropdown_item_1line` use a custom TextView Layout:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/text_dropDown"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="@color/white"
    android:padding="2dp"
    android:textColor="@color/text_light_grey"
    android:textSize="@dimen/text_medium" >
</TextView>
```

Comment: That code won't show the row selection when a user taps on the textview though right?

Comment: You can add a selector as background

Answer (score 1):

try to use this way...

```
tv = (TextView) mInflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, parent, false);
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue is similar to a well known issue when using `ListView`.

http://android-developers.blogspot.fr/2009/01/why-is-my-list-black-android.html

The solution is to use the `cacheColorHint` attribute, but the attribute doesn't exist for `AutoCompleteTextView`, so how to set it ? Actually you have to set it on the drop down menu.

Apply a custom style to the drop down :

```
<item name="dropDownListViewStyle">@style/Widget.YourApp.DropDownListView</item>
```

Set a value to the `cacheColorHint` :

```
<style name="Widget.YourApp.DropDownListView" parent="android:Widget.ListView.DropDown">
    <item name="android:cacheColorHint">@android:color/transparent</item>
</style>
```